# Chrome does not open on Windows 10 as of 09/03/2015?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

Chrome worked this morning, now I come home from work, and Chrome is not working. I can’t find any news on this. I am running Windows 10 pro 64 bit. Chrome crashes on load, did Chrome update or something? Anyone else having this issue? I will try going to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what cause this event, but I uninstalled chrome and reinstalled using the full installer, not the web installer, and now it works. I am running version 45.0.2454.85, did not check what version I had before uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling Chrome, I realized it had automatically selected 32bit for my machine even though I'm running 64 bit Windows 8.1. After downloading for other operating system (64 bit) it seems to work.